# how to escape accented chars on post method with NodeJS-JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, char, escaping

I need to escape a string as "città" or a more complex string such as "la città di Roma".
I am sending this string in a JSON format message via POST method to a remote web service.
I use querystring.escape() but there's no way to get the remote server decode it correctly, in fact it  receives  "city�" instead of "città". 
I have tried to send the string as 'citt\u00e0' and also set the string.SetEncoding to UTF-8 but no way.

This is the code:

```
let strRicerca='città; //  citt\u00e0

strRicerca.setEncoding='UTF-8';
strRicerca=querystring.escape(strRicerca);


  const options = {
    hostname: 'XX.xx.xx.xx, 
    port: 8080, 
    path: '/path/to/service?searchText='+strRicerca+'&user=&pwd=&ava=XX',
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),
      'Cookie':'JSESSIONID='+sessione   
    }
  };
console.log('path ' + options.path);
```

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That means your remote server isn't decoding as UTF8.

Comment: Another possibility is that you (with your editor) and nodejs are not in agreement on the character encoding of your source file. Try re-saving as UTF-8.

Comment: I checked the character encoding of Visual Studio Code, its UTF-8, tried also on a MS Win10 pc and got the same result. What I know about the remote server: it should be running on Nginx and it seems that another guy had the same problem making a  post call from a Telegram bot. My app is on Heroku server, it receives the string from Google's DialogFlow and send it to the remote ws.

Comment: Got it! I loaded utf8 module and got over it